# phonegap Interface switching slowly

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I use Phonegap for development but in the android platform it runs slow what reason is this

This is I write two pages code:

login code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function verify()
{
    var myurl = "main1.html" + "?"+ wifiConfig
    if($("#devicePassword").val()==jsonObj.dockmatePassword){
         window.location.assign(myurl);
    }else{
         alert("error");
    }
}
</script>
   <body onLoad="loadpage()"> 
    <form data-role="controlgroup">
    <br><label for="userpassword">密码:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="devicePassword" name="userpassword"/> 
    <input type="button" data-inline="true" value="确认" onClick="verify()"/>
    </form>
   </body>
```

mian1.html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getConfigInfo(){

    var url = location.href;

    var t=url.split("?")[1];

    var tmp = t.split("$");

    wifiConfig=decodeURI(tmp[0]);                   
    }
}
</script>
<body onLoad="getConfigInfo()"> 
<li id="version"><a>版本<label id="versions"></label</a></li>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what runs slow? opening the page, verifying the password?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is keeping away from Jquery Mobile for phonegap applications. Definitely jQuery Mobile is the best available mobile framework and may be suitable for mobile web sites. But for me, Jquery Mobile is the worst framework in performance for a phonegap application.

Make both pages in a single HTML file and use frameworks like JQTouch to make it effective as application pages.

If you use different HTML files in phonegap application, transition between pages will be slower.

Comment: yes. but i have to use it. other ways to transition between pages will be faster